# KotlinX Serialization validate input bad json

Tags: json, validation, request, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

Let's say I have a Request data class:

```
data class Request(
   val firstName: String,
   val lastName: String
)
```

which I want to serialize when getting to a specific api route. Using Ktor, it would look like this:

`call.receive<Request>()`

This would work perfectly if I get a valid json such as `{ "firstName: "TestFirst", "lastName": "TestLast" }`

But, what if we get a json object or array instead of the expected string? `{ "firstName: [], "lastName": {} }`?

The library would throw an exception and I wouldn't be able to know we had two different validation problems:

1. firstName must be a valid string (and not an array)
2. lastName must be a valid string (and not an object).

How can I find these errors so that I would be able to map them nicely back to the user in the rest api response?

Comment: Shouldn't just the framework return 400 Bad request?

Comment: Yes, but also a list of all the validation errors so the end user know what went wrong. That's my main problem. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of collecting all errors and no way of getting structured information about those errors, but only by the message of an exception.

Comment: Probably, the problem is that it will throw one error. Maybe I have a solution but it's not very elegant. I Could try and receive<JsonElement> and then manually looking if it's matching the type, validation, etc.. Thanks anyways

Comment: I think this issue is related: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1930

Comment: Yep, thank you very much. Let's hope they add something like this. @aSemy what's your alternative for now? I have a nice idea but it's pretty boilerplate..